# How to cull out observations from columns that are factors which contain NULL values from my data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R which has 74 columns. 60 of these columns are factors, while the rest contain continuous data. Of the columns that are factors, some of them contain NULL as one of the levels. I would like to remove all observations might contain a NULL value. Each observation has an ID column that contains a unique identifying number. I have been using the following code snippet:

```
x <- mydata[which(mydata$column2 == "NULL"), ]
mydata <- mydata[!mydata$ID %in% x$ID, ]
```

However when I repeatedly use this in the following way:

```
x <- mydata[which(mydata$column3 == "NULL"), ]
mydata <- mydata[!mydata$ID %in% x$ID, ]
```

I start getting NAs in my data frame. What am I doing wrong? Appreciate the help.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example/data. Not just the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NAs because you are referring to rows which are no longer in `mydata`. But in any case your idea of repeatedly trimming down the data is not a good idea performance and code clarity wise. Try this instead:

```
mydata<-mydata[!apply(mydata,1,function(x) any(x=="NULL")),]
```

Here you check which rows contain at least one time the value `"NULL"`, and then you remove those rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
# identify the factor columns
factor.cols <- sapply(mydata, is.factor)

# for each row, count how many factor columns contain "NULL"
null.count <- rowSums(mydata[factor.cols]=="NULL")

# keep only those rows with no "NULL" factor values,
# along with rows where all factor values are NA
mydata[is.na(null.count) | null.count==0,]
```

(Edited to do the right thing if a particular row has `NA`s in all the factor columns.)

Comment: ah, just saw the edited addition to @Arun's answer, which is basically the same approach.